# Can the F# compiler optimize these mutually recursive functions?

Tags: recursion, optimization, f#, tail-recursion, mutual-recursion

I wrote the following function that checks the validity of bracketed expressions:

```
let matched str =
    let rec matched' stack = function
        | "" -> isEmpty stack
        | str ->
            match first str with
            | '(' | '[' | '{' as p -> matched' (push p stack) (rest str)
            | ')' -> matchClosing '(' stack str
            | ']' -> matchClosing '[' stack str
            | '}' -> matchClosing '{' stack str
            | _ -> matched' stack (rest str)

    and matchClosing expected stack s =
        match peek stack with
        | Some c when c = expected -> matched' (pop stack) (rest s)
        | _ -> false

    matched' [] str
```

If we substitute the implementation of `matchClosing` into `matched'`, we get a tail recursive function. Can the F# compiler recognize this and optimize away the recursive calls?

Comment: What do you see when you look at the IL that the compiler generates?  That's the only way to tell for sure (e.g. a future version of the compiler could always behave differently).

Comment: But it doesn't really matter that much if the F# compiler detects tail recursion and compiles it in a special way, because the .NET JIT compiler performs tail call elimination anyway.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin - semantically it doesn't matter, but from a performance perspective it can.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

AFAICT your example isn't complete which makes it harder to check. I complemented it somewhat and was able to compile it.

Using `ILSpy` one sees that the mutual recursion is still in place:

```
// F#: | ')' -> matchClosing '(' stack str
case ')':
    return Program.matchClosing@39('(', stack, str);

// F#: | matched' t (tail s)
return Program.matched'@28(t, s.Tail);
```

So while it should be technically possible to unpack two mutually tail recursive function into a loop it's not done.

When checking the IL code we see that the the calls are tagged with `.tail`

```
// F#: | matchClosing '(' stack str
IL_0083: tail.  // Here
IL_0085: call bool Program::matchClosing@39(char, class [FSharp.Core]Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.FSharpList`1<char>, valuetype Program/SubString)

// F#: | matched' t (tail s)
IL_002a: tail.  // Here
IL_002c: call bool Program::'matched\'@28'(class [FSharp.Core]Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.FSharpList`1<char>, valuetype Program/SubString)
```

The .NET Jitter is in release mode kind enough to consider `.tail` flag

```
// As you can see when debugging the code in WinDbg
02410bdf e8fbd3176b      call    clr!JIT_TailCall (6d58dfdf)
```

We also see when we debug in WinDbg that the stack don't grow. Unfortunately when looking at `clr!JIT_TailCall` it does a fair amount of work meaning while it doesn't consume stack it consumes clock cycles instead like noted here: [How to eliminate time spent in JIT_TailCall for functions that are genuinely non-recursive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31433605/how-to-eliminate-time-spent-in-jit-tailcall-for-functions-that-are-genuinely-non)

However in Debug mode (and at least older versions of Mono) `.tail` flag is ignored

```
// As you can see when debugging the code in WinDbg (this is a normal call)
02f619c1 e8c2f4ffff      call    02f60e88
```

We also see when we debug in WinDbg that the stack grow.

So the answer to your question should be:

1. No, the F# compiler isn't able to transform the mutually tail recursive calls into a loop.
2. However, the F# compiler tags the calls with a `.tail` attribute
3. The Release mode JIT:er kindly considers the `.tail` attributes and generates tail calls that don't grow the stack (but are ineffecient)
4. In Debug mode (and possibly mono) `.tail` attributes are ignored and no tail calls are generated by the JIT:er and the stack will grow.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! It's very interesting to see that this optimization is done by the JIT compiler - I would never have thought of that!

Comment: Great answer. Tails call do work on Mono as well since 2.1x.